# Puppet schedule metaparameters not executing properly

Tags: puppet

**I have a puppet schedule as below:**

```
schedule { 'everyday':
        period => daily,
        range  => "0 -9"
        repeat => 3,
    }
```

I was assuming this will run 3 times between 0AM to 9AM right. But it doesn't looks to be running.

My puppet is running by cron every 15 minutes. So, when can i assume it will run.

Or could some one please explain me the relation-ship between repeat, range and daily.

thank you in adv.

Answer (score 2):

Your puppet schedule is having a syntax error, missed a comma after range attribute. Have you tried to run **puppet apply** to parse your **.pp** file?

instead of

---

```
schedule { 'everyday':
        period => daily,
        range  => "0 -9"
        repeat => 3,
    }
```

try this

```
schedule { 'everyday':
    period => daily,
    range  => "0-9",
    repeat => 3,
}
```

Comment: What's the difference? Does that matter?

Comment: @E.Coms Without the comma after the value, the syntax is invalid and it won't parse properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about what it should do but I think you got a typo.
Range parameter definiton from puppet: 

`This is always a hyphen-separated range within a 24 hour period, and hours must be specified in numbers between 0 and 23, inclusive`

so as you can see it is "hyphen-seperated". That's lacking.

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#schedule-attribute-range

Comment: it runs three times a day between midnight and 9 AM. when? you can't tell. if you want to be sure make cronjob

Answer (score 0):

@3h4x and @James Sapam

Any resource in your puppet classes which uses the **everyday** schedule, will be executed for 3 time and usually will run with the first 3 (`or whatever repeat value is mentioned`) puppet runs between the time span mentioned. It will be skipped for the rest period of the day (`i.e. from 09:00 to 23:59`)

Check the **maint** schedule in [this link](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.10/type.html#schedule-attributes)